# Do fine grit sand papers and wax polish bars and pastes have a universal color code?

Tags: polishing

Im talking about 10k 5k 2k 1k 800 400 grit papers, wax polishing bars and polish paste.

Do they have a universal color code which corresponds to grit?

Many times the letters are either not on the paper or hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they do not. I've got red, yellow, green, and grey 800 grit in a drawer in my garage!

I also have various different grit values that are all grey.